# SoundBoard error no visible @interface for 'NSBundle' declares the selector 'pathForRescource:ofType:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

i am trying to make a simple audio board application, i am following the Apple documentation on the AVFoundationPlayer, but i keep getting this error (no visible @interface for 'NSBundle' declares the selector 'pathForRescource:ofType:' ) and i have searched for an hour, with no result.

my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {



}
//actions
-(IBAction)playSound1;
-(IBAction)playSound2;
-(IBAction)playSound3;
-(IBAction)playSound4;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

@end

my .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()


@end



@implementation ViewController
@synthesize player;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    NSString *soundFilePath1 =
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForRescource: @"trumpet"
                                     ofType: @"mp3"];

    NSURL *fileURL1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath1];


    AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer =
    [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL1 error:nil];

    [fileURL1 release];

    self.player= newPlayer;

    [newPlayer release];

    [player prepareToPlay];

    [player setDelegate: self];



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

@end

If i can provide any other details i would be happy to help and thank you for reading.

Comment: Instead of updating the title with "SOLVED", you should accept the answer that pointed out your issue.

Comment: New user! Didn't even know about that feature, thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo. You have written pathForRescource: and it is `pathForResource:ofType:`.

`- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension`

Comment: Thank you so much! I do apologise for wasting your time! But thank you!